# Characterizing the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with LUB property

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, order-theory

Say a subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ has $\textbf{least-upper-bound property (LUBP)}$ if every nonempty bounded above subset $T \subset S$ has supremum that exists in $S$.

I want to characterize the LUBP subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I know that all closed intervals and singeltons have LUBP, and moreover, the union of two LUBP sets is LUBP, since if $S = A \cup B$ and $T \subset S$, then $\sup T = \max(\sup(T \cap A),~\sup(T \cap B))$), so certainly any finite union of closed intervals and singeltons have LUBP, but then we're still missing sets like $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any discrete closed set should work, as well as half closed intervals $(a,b]$.

Comment: When you say "bounded subset of $S$", do you mean "bounded in $\Bbb R$" or "bounded in $S$"? This makes a difference, as in the first case, an open interval $(a,b)$ would not have the LUBP, while in the second case, it would.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ probably? I am not exactly sure what "bounded in $X$" means actually, but in the OP I am just saying a subset $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above if there exists $C$ such that $p < C$ for all $p \in T$.

Comment: In the OP, you say $T\subset S$, and even though $S\subset \Bbb R$, this is a different thing. When you say "there exists $C$", you don't mention *where* $C$ gets to exist. It cannot exist just anywhere, as $\Bbb R$ lies in larger sets such as the extended reals, where $+\infty$ is an upper bound for everything. Of course you do not mention the extended reals, so that is not a valid interpretation. But you do mention both $S$ and $\Bbb R$, so it is unclear whether $C$ must be in $S$ or can be in $\Bbb R$. If $S = (-1,1)$, and $T = [0,1)$, then $T$ is bounded in $\Bbb R$ but not in $S$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, I see what you mean. In all cases I mean bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, so that for example if $S$ is bounded (in $\mathbb{R}$), then the supremum for every subset would have to exist for $S$ to have the LUBP.

Comment: Not just all closed intervals, but all closed sets have this property (a set is closed if it contains all of its limit points). But there are non-closed sets with the property as well. As Justin Young pointed out, any interval containing its upper end point will also have the property even if it is open on the lower end. I think one characterization of these sets would be they are exactly the closed sets of the lower limit topology (the topology you get by considering closed-above, open-below intervals as being open sets).

Answer (score 0):

(After the comment of Paul Sinclair). Consider the topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by intervals of the form $(a,b]$.

Claim: The closed sets are the subsets of $\mathbb R$ with the least upper bound property.

Proof: Consider a closed set $C$ and a subset $T\subset C$ so that $T$ has an upper bound $M$, then $t\le M$ for all $t \in T$. Let $m = $ the supremum of all elements of $T$, we know that $m$ exists as a real number as long as $T$ is nonempty. Consider $m\in (a,b]$, then we have $a<m$ and by definition of $m$ there must exist $t \in T$ such that $a<t\le m$, so $(a,b]\cap C \neq \emptyset$. It follows that $m\in C$.

Finally, let $C$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$ with the least upper bound property and consider $x\in \mathbb R\setminus C = U$. Let $T=\{c\in C \vert c\le x\}$. If $T$ is empty then $(a,x]\subset U$ for any $a<x$. If $T$ is non empty, observe that $x$ is an upper bound for $T$ and therefore the supremum of $T$, call it $s$, is also in $C$. In this case, we must have $s<x$, and therefore $(s,x]\subset U$. It follows that $C$ is closed.